# How to create a single-question quiz in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-component, react-dom

How do I implement the logic for correct and incorrect answers? I have created a single-question quiz with multiple options. I have created a `Quiz` component. Here is the source:

**Quiz Component**

```
export default function Quiz(props) {
  
  return (
    <div className="QuizContainer">
      <div className="quizHeader">
        <h1>Question</h1>
        <p className="PracticeDescription">
          Read the question and choose the most correct option.
        </p>
      </div>
      <hr/>

      <div className="PracticeQuestionContainer">
        <p>{props.question}</p>

        <div class="option-container">
          <input type="radio" name="select" id="option-1" className="input-radio" />
          <input type="radio" name="select" id="option-2" className="input-radio" />
          <input type="radio" name="select" id="option-3" className="input-radio" />
          <input type="radio" name="select" id="option-4" className="input-radio" />

          <label for="option-1" className="option option-1">
            <div className="dot"></div>
            <span>{props.option1}</span>
          </label>

          <label for="option-2" className="option option-2">
            <div className="dot"></div>
            <span>{props.option2}</span>
          </label>

          <label for="option-3" className="option option-3">
            <div className="dot"></div>
            <span>{props.option3}</span>
          </label>

          <label for="option-4" className="option option-4">
            <div className="dot"></div>
            <span>{props.option4}</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And I have used this component on the page like this:

```html
<Quiz
  question="1. Which one is not a JavaScript variable?"
  option1="var a=5"
  option2="let b=6"
  option3="const c=3"
  option4="int x=9"
/>
```

Here how it looks like:

[image]

**If the user selects the correct answer, it should** `colsole.log("Correct!") else console.log("Incorrect!")`. How do I do this? Please help me!!

Comment: Please in react

Comment: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/adding-interactivity

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'd also need to pass a correct answer to your **Quiz** component, after which you'd need to take a look at event handling, so whenever user clicks an option, a function gets called which compares clicked answer with the correct answer.

Read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Can you edit the code? How to handle the event?